# Android: Getting Checkbox value from Parent Activity

Tags: android, inheritance, checkbox

I have one parent Activity, which has following code.

```
void parentMethod(){
    c1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    c2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    c3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
   if(c1.isChecked()){
        p.setC1("1");
   }
   if(c2.isChecked()){
        p.setC2("1");
   }
   if(c3.isChecked()){
        p.setC3("1");
   }
}
```

Here *c1*,*c2*,*c3* are `checkboxes`.

Now I have one child activity which is extending above mentioned parent activity.

```
void childMethod(){
     super.parentMethod();
}
```

It's giving me `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `if(c1.isChecked())` in parent method.

Is there any way I can get the checkbox values from parent class?

Comment: Do you use same layout for the child activity?

Comment: No, it has different layout

Comment: Does the layout (that is used by child activity) contain those 3 checkboxes?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  3 checkboxes are only in parent layout. So I cant use those values in child activity?

Comment: of course you can't, in order for the values c1,c2,c3 to be populated the onCreate of the parent activity has to be called and the acitivity shouldn't be onPause, it will not hold references then, You should use fragments instead of child activity, fragments are better suited here.